# How can you make UITableView a subview of UIView retrospectively?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a view controller (subclass of UIViewController, not UITableViewController), with a table view as a subview. I now want to put another view on that screen, but can't resize the table view to not take up the entire screen, or drag in a view above that. It seems that the view can only contain a single table view. I know it's possible to have a table view and other views within the same screen, so what am i missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your view hierarchy on left - your `view` is subview of `tableView`. And you need to have something like

```
ViewController.view
               |--> view
               |--> tableView
```

And you have

```
ViewController.tableView
               |--> view
```

***Edit***

What should you do

1. Copy (Cmd-C) your Table view. Than delete it
   [image: Clean controller]
2. Drag View to your View Controller

[image: Root view only]

3. Choose View and paste Table view to it (Cmd-V)
   [image: Table view with subview]
4. Drag View from Table view upwards to root view of Controller
   [image: Exactly what you want]

Now, you can position your view and table view however you want

Comment: yes - that's perfect, sorry for delay in accepting. thank you!